# Rails database password as environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, yaml

This works:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: myapp
  username: myapp
  password: jksdfUIJsdf
```

Then on terminal `touch tmp/restart.txt`.

This does not work:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: myapp
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Then on terminal

```
export MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=jksdfUIJsdf
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

So if I set the password as plaintext in database.yml file then my application works properly but if I set the password as environment variable with export command, then my application does not work because it gives error password missing. I am using mysql database. How to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you do 'puts ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD']' in the rails console?

Answer (score 2):

When you touch `tmp/restart.txt`, you're not starting a new Rails server, you're just telling the existing server to reload itself. The existing server will still have the environment it started with, and will never see any environment variables you set after that time.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails app configuration, I use [figaro gem.](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Add the below line to your `Gemfile` and do `bundle`.

```
gem "figaro"
```

After that run the below command:

```
bundle exec figaro install
```

This will create `config/application.yml` and also will add it to the `.gitignore` file.

Now inside `config/application.yml` enter the credentials.

```
# config/application.yml

MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD: "2954"
```

Visit [the Github page for more info.](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)